# Save User Automatically in Database

Tags: python, django

Here's my Model,

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

So, whenever the 'request.user' calls a specific view i.e,

```
def myview(request):
....
....
return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```

I wants to save the 'user' (request.user) & 'timestamp' (current time as per their location) automatically in database. Also I wants to update the timestamp without repeating model in database. How can I do that in view?

Please help me with this code. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#request-started signal

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I think `signal` should be used  when creation or updation of one model should affect another model. In this situation I think below answer should be good.